# Excluding globs in the classpath for compilation with IntelliJ Idea 11

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Can I exclude matched paths in IntelliJ Idea 11.

I have .git folders being inserted into my binaries.  My colleagues with Eclipse can set matched paths in the classpathentry exclude=""

Thanks,
Ty

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` | `File Types` | `Ignore Files and Folders`? If it's not what you are looking for, clarify the problem with the sample project.

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation, however that is such that the editor ignores that file type.  I'm currently building an android project through Idea 11, and all of the .git folders are included in the .apk file that is generated.

In Eclipse I can specify the compiler to ignore all .git, however in Idea, I must specify each path manually under the Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes, and can not use a general mask such as ".git".  Any proposed resolution?

Comment: There must be something wrong with your Settings | Compiler | Resource Patterns or File Types, .git folders should not be copied into apk by default. Or it could be some project misconfiguration, can you share a sample project to reproduce it?

Comment: We are using git-svn, so the .git folder has the svn info under it, which includes files, etc... these seem to be whats included.  I've tried adding multiple negated paths to the resource patterns including

!/**/.git
!/**/.git/*
!.git
!.git/*
!*.git

I'll try to create a sample project later in the day from svn, then through git svn, and see if I can get a similar behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: .git folder is excluded by default, so no files from this folder should be copied and it doesn't happen for other users as far as we know.

Comment: We did a git-svn clone, then iterated through all svn externals to create and did a recursive git-svn clone on them.  so each subfolder that contains a .git folder has an svn folder inside of that which would contain resources, class file, etc... based on what svn is storing.  When our APK is compiled we see the size around 22mb, in eclipse we can specify the exclude of **/.git and it's 6mb.  In Intellij I can manually add those 9 paths and it works, however I'd like to see a solution that works for all git-svn directories from svn:externals.  Any thoughts or should I work on a sample proj?

Comment: As .git is already ignored, everything under .git should be also ignored, including your svn folders. Please provide a sample project.