# .apk includes .git folder

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I am in the very odd situation where my `.apk` files, both in debug and release mode, as exported by Eclipse, include the `.git` folder! I can not figure out why, I also checked the Java Build Path, nothing interesting in there.

Thank you,

Comment: Somewhat relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070484/excluding-globs-in-the-classpath-for-compilation-with-intellij-idea-11

Comment: Looks like this is similar, but no solution is presented there. I think that this happened when I tried to experiment with ProGuard, but not sure though, as I had never checked the .apk before. I rolled-back all my files and project settings to the pre-ProGuard state and I still have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [not have the git repository inside the Eclipse workspace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse). That would avoid this and a lot of other potential trouble.

Instead, the git repository should be one of the parents of your Eclipse project.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it is not straight-forward to move the repository, I need to look into more details on that.